# Response of a Jersey REST service isn't including null fields

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have this Jersey REST service:

```
@GET
@Path("/consult")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response consult() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Pedro");
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new Gson().toJson(person)).build();
}
```

.

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    ...

}
```

Which gives me this JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pedro"
  }
]
```

Why the `age` field isn't included in the JSON response as `null`? And how can I include it?

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pedro",
    "age": null
  }
]
```

**EDIT:**

I have already tried using `@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)` like:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    ...

}
```

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Gson to serialize your object. Gson by default removes null values. To include null values use:

```
public Response consult() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .serializeNulls()
        .create();
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Pedro");
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(gson.toJson(person)).build();
}
```

[More info](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/serialize-null-values/)

Answer (score 2):

Who 'include' fields it's GSON lib.
You can use the GsonBuilder to create a single instance of gson and you can configure your gson parser like it:

```
class .... {
  static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting() // build json formatted (optional)
        .serializeNulls() // include null fields
        .create();
```

then you use gson

```
return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(gson.toJson(person)).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this annotation should solve your issue
@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but I'd already tried this and it didn't work for me.